# Laravel basic Database 'with' function

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function GetStock()

{
    $whatstock=stock::all() ;
    $max=stock::max('idStock') ;
    return view('welcome')->with('zzz',$max) 
                          ->with('any',$whatstock) ;
```

i get it thankyou for answering :).

Comment: Your second return is unreachable since you're already returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return view twice, so change it it:

```
return view('welcome', ['zzz' => $max, 'any' => $whatstock]);
```

Or:

```
return view('welcome')->with('zzz', $max)->with('any', $whatstock);
```